# How to dispose a list of disposable objects?

Tags: .net, vb.net, idisposable

I am implementing IDisposable for a class and while disposing there is a internal list of disposable objects. Should I be disposing those object by looping through them.

```
public Class MyDisposable 
     Implements IDisposable 
     private _disposbaleObjects as new List(of OtherDisposables)

     Public Overloads Sub Dispose() Implements System.IDisposable.Dispose
         Dispose(True)
         GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                  ? Should I dispose the the list like this ?
                  For Each obj In _disposbaleObjects
                      obj.dispose()
                  Next 
            End If               
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: The "Overloads" keyword is wrong, remove it.  The VB.NET IDE generates inappropriate boilerplate code for 99.9% of all IDisposable implementations.  Just move the disposing code to Sub Dispose() and get rid of the protected method and SuppressFinalize.

Comment: @Hans, Can you tell the reason for your suggestion ?

Comment: The boilerplate code is appropriate only when you implement a finalizer.  That's extremely rare.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, iterate through the list and dispose each item.

Also you can write an extension method:

```
public static void Dispose(this IEnumerable<IDisposable> collection)
{
    foreach (IDisposable item in collection)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            try
            {
                item.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // log exception and continue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call it for your list

```
coll.Dispose()
```

Disposable collection, a collection that implements `IDisposable`:

```
public sealed class DisposableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, IDisposable
    where T : IDisposable
{
    public DisposableCollection(IList<T> items)
        : base(items)
    {
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            try
            {
                item.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
                // swallow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var coll = new DisposableCollection(items))
{
     // use
}
// it has been disposed
```

Comment: Does VB.Net have extension methods?

Comment: +1 Or alternatively inherit from `List` to define an object that does it for you? http://willsmentaldebris.blogspot.com/2007/08/disposable-container-class.html

Comment: what about methods like Clear(), Remove()? They should be overridden with ones taking into account the fact that disposable object is owned by collection.

Answer (score 3):

Who creates the objects inside the list? i.e. who is responsible for their life-cycle? If `MyDisposable` creates them, then it is its responsibility to dispose of them. If someone else creates them, disposing of them can leave them with a reference to a useless object.

Comment: MyDisposable creates the list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to dispose each of these objects explicitly, exactly the way you're doing it now.